# If you use the Scrapy framework to crawl large amounts of data, the item object will run out of memory？

Tags: python, scrapy

I tried to crawl a lot of data in Python, but I wondered if the item object would run out of memory during data persistence as the amount of data grew

Answer (score 0):

Yes it probably will. I've done large jobs and eventually it crashed. The RAM memory limit on your system will depend though. Maybe you can solve it by saving the items into textfiles or similar and then delete the items from memory.

When I need to to large scraping jobs I will usually just divide it into smaller jobs. If you're scraping the same website, like `example.com?page={page_number}` you can limit to say 10 000 pages and when you run the spider the second time you continue on page 10 000. You'll need to save down what page you're currently on though, in a text file through and API.

Answer (score 0):

try to use some memory debugger and see which objects are causing memory leaks  .. while using scrappy keep a close eye on your `meta` values in most of the cases that are the primary reason of memory issue in large crawls

you should read out some scrapy documentation here. so you can debug memory leaks

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/leaks.html

Answer (score 0):

Item objects are not kept in memory forever, as data is persisted they are removed from memory, so unless each item object is *extremely* big (unlikely), a large number of item objects should never be a problem.

You are more likely to run out of disk, depending on the amount of data you are extracting. Make sure you have enough disk wherever you are persisting the extracted data.